# Cross domain call through JSONP

Tags: ajax, extjs, cross-domain, jsonp

I want to display html pages from external domains but unable to do this through JSONP i.e when page loads,page doesn't contain anything. It just shows a blank page. Please find my code below for reference.
Code:

```
  Ext.util.JSONP.request({                
             url:wikiurl,
            callbackKey:'callback',
            params:{},
            callback:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                console.log("inside callback");
            },
            success:function(result,opts){
                console.log(result);
            },
               failure:function(result,opts){
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

=>what is the URL?

=>who is sending the response, you need to send specific response from server when some one need JASONP data.

=>you are logging everything to console, it wont show in page, probably in firebug console or similar console it would be visible.

=>to see response in page, just dump the data in a div element in page.

Comment: see [How it Works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#How_it_works) section in :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP